# Mapping jsonb columns to java model using rowMapper

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc, jsonb

My database tables has a few `jsonb` columns. I am using PostgreSQL e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE trades (  
  id serial NOT NULL, 
  accounts jsonb,
  //..
  //..
);
```

I need to map these `jsonb` columns to my data model using Spring `RowMapper` `mapRow()`:

```
public class DataModelRowMapper implements RowMapper<TestModel> {


    @Override
    public TestModel mapRow(final ResultSet rs,
                                 final int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        List<Account> accounts = jsonParser.parse(rs.getString("accounts"), new TypeReference<List<Account>>() {
        });

        //other jsonb columns



        Account account = accounts.stream()
                                                    .filter(account -> account.getType() == Type.CLIENT)
                                                    .findFirst()
                                                    .orElse(new Account());


        final TestModel testModel = new TestModel();
        testModel.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        testModel.setAccountName(account.getName());


        return testModel;
    }

}
```

Inside `mapRow()`, I parse the json to a Java `List` and then stream through to find the appropriate value as multiple `accounts` are returned. I have a few additional jsonb columns for which I do similar operations inside `mapRow()`.

Previously, I was returning the exact values from the SQL query itself which proved to be slow and then moved this filtering logic to inside `mapRow()` in java code as the intention is to increase performance and return the result.

My question is, should I be parsing and filtering logic inside mapRow ? Is there a better faster way of loading `jsonb` data and mapping to `TestModel` `accountName` string property ?

My issue is, the sql query runs quick <1 ms on the db, but the java layer is adding some overhead.

Comment: "Should I be parsing and filtering logic inside `mapRow`?" It's not very efficient to do it for every row. Can you modify the query so you return only the client account (and perhaps similar for other jsonb columns)? Did you know you can index `jsonb` columns in Postgres?

Comment: how can you return only the client account in the SELECT? I previously had a CTE query which proved costly.

Comment: Well multiple ways, CTE, subselect (although the query planner might have a fit). Maybe your CTE would have been snappier with indexes (b-tree or gin) on the relevant jsonb values? Which postgres version are you on?

Comment: On Postgres 12 there's also `jsonb_path_query_first` function that could be used in place of subselect. But you obviously want to keep as much processing in the database as possible, as long as you do it efficiently there. Moving the processing to Java side won't help, unless you've got a really suboptimal database setup. This is all I can say based on the information you've given in your question.

Comment: Can you show an example ?

Comment: An example of what?

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the whole system, you may not need to parse into the fields at all.
for example, in most cases, it is required to return the JSON without modifications. just return the string. no need to parse back and forth, it's really faster.

example spring mvc:

```
// a method that returns a list of objects in JSON by search criteria
        @RequestMapping(value = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody
        void getAll(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody final Entity request) throws IOException {
            List<String> res = null;
            try {
                List<Entity>  regList =  entityDAO.getAll(request); // get from DB list of objects with JSON
                res = regList.stream().map(h -> h.getJson_obj()).collect(Collectors.toList()); // just collect JSONs
    //            res = regList.stream().map(h -> h.getJson_obj().replaceFirst("\\{", "{ \"vehicle_num\":" + h.getVehicle_num() + ",")).collect(Collectors.toList()); //it is also possible to add dynamic data without parsing
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("getAll ", e);
            }

            String resStr = "[" + res.stream().filter(t -> t != null).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "]"; // join in one String

            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
            response.setStatus(200);
            response.getWriter().println(resStr);
        }
```

ps sorry, I can't leave a comment, so the answer.